# Trace id 2 stopped because disk space, but I can't find this trace

Tags: sql-server-2014

I received the famous alert:

```
Trace ID '2' was stopped because of an error. Cause: 0x80070070(There is not enough space on the disk.). Restart the trace after correcting the problem.
```

But running both queries to check traces:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.traces

select * from fn_trace_getinfo(default)
```

i can't find any trace ID = 2

[image]

So I have 2 questions:

1. How can I find this trace? Is it not showing because it's not running? How can I check all traces ( running or not ) because both SELECT * FROM `sys.traces` and `select * from fn_trace_getinfo(0)` shows nothing.
2. How can I start a trace?
   is `EXEC sp_trace_setstatus TRACE_ID,1(turn on)` right?

Comment: If you look in the SQL Server log you should be able to see when it was started and by what login but no other info I think

Comment: `sys.traces` will show all traces (running and stopped) but not those that were closed and the definition deleted (`sp_trace_setstatus` status 2). Those traces will need to be recreated. Check for a SQL agent job or startup proc that (re)creates the trace.

Comment: got it. thanks, I thought it was strange because the error message says "the trace stopped" and not "deleted". I ran the script again and the trace was created.

Comment: I could totally understand now. One of the traces were a default one, and one was created by us.

By `sp_configure 'default trace enabled',1
reconfigure with override` I enabled one of them and with the script enabled the second one.